# Should I be using class instance methods in an angular template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I work on an angular project where we use interfaces very heavily and classes very sparingly. There is definitely an argument to add classes for some of our objects, but I am confused about the best practice of using class instance methods in an angular template. Most of what I read on the topic I interpret as "absolutely never ever use a method in a template", but I assume I'm probably being overzealous and I should rather just be careful to ensure the method does not do a lot of processing?

By way of contrived example let's say I have a really basic class, something like:

```
class MyClass {
    private someNumbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

    hasTheNumberFive(): boolean {
        return this.someNumbersArray.includes(5);
    }
}
```

Now lets assume I have an array of those classes in my component called `myClassesArray`. In the template, I'd be inclined to do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myClassesArray">
  <div *ngIf="item.hasTheNumberFive()">
    // do whatever (and lets assume there is an else block too)
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously this becomes a performance issue if I have a huge myClassesArray, or the someNumbersArray is huge. Is there a better way to do this that will protect me against potential performance issues?

One thought was it may be better to create a component for rendering this MyClass, and passing the instance to it as an Input(), and then calculating the result of hasTheNumberFive() in ngOnInit() and storing it as a public property on the component, and reference that in the *ngIf?

Comment: *I assume I'm probably being overzealous and I should rather just be careful to ensure the method does not do a lot of processing?*: you got it absolutely right. Your solution would work fine, as long as MyClass is immutable. If you compute the value in ngOnInit but later change the content of the array, your ngIf won't notice the change, since it will still use the value that has been computed at initialization time.

Comment: I'm usually against using methods inside templates. If you want to use computed data inside the template, you can make use of getters. Also, a method inside a template can sometimes be replaced by a **pure pipe**. You can achieve memoization through using pipes. Find out more in this [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybNj-id0kjY&t=1481s)